# Adding CookieManager to android Childbrowser

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, childbrowser

I am trying to get local cookies (file://) to work on android 3.1+
within ChildBrowser. I found a blog response talking about this
specific issue and how to remedy it with Cookie Manager. I can't
figure out where in the plugin to put the code. Has anyone
successfully implemented this?

---

Comment Below from http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3739

Comment 16 by edtechk...@gmail.com, Feb 1, 2012
I got this thing working, for Android 2.2, javascript's
document.cookie works fine, just make sure that in your
Webview...javascript is enabled like so:

```
yourWebViewVariable.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

for Android 3.1 just add this to your java file onLoadInit:

```
CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);   //This is the line that specifically makes it work so the other lines is optional

CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
cookieManager.acceptCookie();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those interested, I figured it out. It is not a Childbrowser issue at all. You have to make the parent Phonegap project accept local cookies and then Childbrowser will too.
To do so, You should have a file called youappname.java in your PhoneGap project, probably with this contents or similar:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class App extends DroidGap {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
}
```

Modify it to look like this example:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class App extends DroidGap {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
}
```